# How to display the first 100 characters in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, string

I use a gridview to display data, but sometimes the data is to big to be displayed in a cell. Can I use a method to allow the gridview to display f.e. the first 100 characters of a string?

any help is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle the RowDataBound event of the gridview and cut the text length, like so:

```
protected void gvNotes_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    int _myColumnIndex = 0;   // Substitute your value here

    string text = e.Row.Cells[_myColumnIndex].Text;

    if (text.Length > 100)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[_myColumnIndex].Text = text.Substring(0, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with databinding :s
if you could see what happened with the data you will laugh.
I'm getting data allover my screen :s

Comment: I don't want to reduce the size of the string. I just need to show a small part of the data in gridview

Answer (score 0):

For an IE only answer, you could use CSS and, as long as you have a set width for the column, set overflow:ellipsis, or overflow:hidden (should work for all browsers), if you don't want the dots.

---

OK, as per the comment, I haven't used gridviews for a while, but it would be a matter of setting a CSS class for each of those cells and in the class:

```
trimText
{
   overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

There's also some hacking you can do to get this to display cross browser - some notes here:

http://www.jide.fr/english/emulate-text-overflowellipsis-in-firefox-with-css

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do. how can I achieve this please

Answer (score 0):

Create this function

```
public object TrimString(string input, int length)
    {
        // return nothing if the string is null
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        // invalid length submitted
        if (length <= 0)
        {
            length = 100;
        }

        if (input.Length > length)
        {
            return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
        }

        return input;
    }
```

And you call it from your aspx page like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# TrimString(Eval("CustName").ToString(),100) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```