# the reapter to display the first 100 characters of a string and after that a hyperlink to display next page

Tags: asp.net

use a reapeter to display data, but sometimes the data is to big to be displayed in a cell. Can I use a method to allow the reapter to display the first 100 characters of a string and after that a hyperlink to display next page?  any help is welcome!

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234441/how-to-display-the-first-100-characters-in-a-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave this logic in the view:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" 
 Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "your_text_field").ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(100, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "your_text_field").ToString().Length %>' />
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" Test='<%# Eval("your_text_field") %>' 
     Visible='<%# Eval("your_text_field").ToString().Length > 100 %>' />
```

Comment: it give an error 'Newline in constant' for label near Math.Min

Comment: this happens if you break the line copying or if you miss a quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the implementation details of your code, so this is a shot in the dark.  If you  are binding an object, create a new property that takes the first 100 characters of the information you want displayed:

```
class Foo 
{
   public String PropertyData {get;set;} //your real data;
   public String DisplayData //bind the reader to this property instead.
   {
       get 
       {
           return PropertyData.substring
            (0, (PropertyData.Length >= 100) ? 100 : PropertyData.Length);
       }
   }
}
```

You can have the property return anything you want, this is just an example of how to get it to display only 100 characters.